# How to disable local data cache in Windows Form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a vb.net Windows Form that is launched from the .application file - no installing done. I have an issue on some users' machines where they can't launch the application unless they go into their C:\Users\%userprofile%\local settings\apps\ folder and delete folder "2.0".

How can I prevent the application from using/creating that cache? All user settings are stored server-side and pulled down on open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found AN answer, maybe not the best, but it works.

Turns out, ClickOnce is the problem. I haven't been able to figure out how to deploy without it, however it can be bypassed. Within the deployment folder, you've got an Application Files folder, and a [Project Name]_[version] folder. Within that is the .exe for your application, within the ClickOnce wrapper.

If your application, like mine, doesn't use non built-in controls, you don't actually need ClickOnce, as far as I can tell. So having users run that .exe, rather than the .application file within the deployment folder will prevent the "2.0" cache folder, as well as preventing the ClickOnce install and loading form - resulting in a faster open.

Hope that helps someone.